# Is it possible to use Lombok annotations as a meta-annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I want to define my own annotation for transfer objects and include there some Lombok annotations as meta-annotations:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public @interface TransferObject {
}
```

The intent is to annotate all my transfer objects with `@TransferObject` and "inherit" all of the above. In practice it doesn't work, classes annotated with `@TransferObject` are not processed by Lombok.

Is there some way to get this working? If not, it it theoretically possible to enhance Lombok to look for meta-annotations?

Note: I'm on Java 8.

UPDATE: It looks like there's a [feature request](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/557) for this on github.

Comment: ... maybe we should just introduce macro in java, and get over it:)

Comment: You answered your own question. Add an answer and I happily upvote it :)

Answer (score 26):

Short answer is NOT (for current version 1.18.4 - Oct 30, 2018)

According to the thread [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/557):

> This feature would require resolution in a very early stage of processing. Currently that is not possible. Possibly, since we now have the lombok configuration system, we might come up with a different solution.

Actually, they have several requests of the similar functionality on Lombok's [GitHub page](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) - non of them is implemented.

Please consider upvoting [this](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1993) feature or [this](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/557) one.