# How can I have an annotation add other annotations to a class in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

I have an annotation called `@ConfigData`.  Its usage is as follows: `@ConfigData(name = "example", type = "yaml")`

When I use this on a class, I also need to have other annotations on it.  These primarily consist of lombok annotations, such as `@Data` and `@NoArgsConstructor`.

I would like to have the `@ConfigData` annotation add these other annotations to the class it is used on.

If this is possible, how would I go about it?

Comment: This is not generally possible in Java. Groovy has such support in `AnnotationCollector`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635108/adding-java-annotations-at-runtime

Comment: Regarding Lombok specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512957/is-it-possible-to-use-lombok-annotations-as-a-meta-annotation