# How can I unify 2 annotations into one in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, annotations, tostring

I want to know if there is a way to unify 2 annotations
For example I want to use both @ToString.Exclude and @JsonIgnore on particular fields in classes throughout my code, but I would like to unify them into one custom annotation.
(fields can also have other annotations apart from these)
How can I do that in Java? (Java 11, Spring Boot)
Thanks!

Comment: What you're looking for is called "meta-annotations" (i.e. put an annotation onto another annotation, so that the other one acts as the equivalent of every other annotation on it). Whether or not that's supported depends on what tools are interpreting the annotation (there's no language-level support for this in Java, each framework has to build support for this on its own). It seems that [Lombok doesn't support it yet (feature request from 2015)](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/557). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512957/).